# Is there an easy way to produce or upgrade a lot of ships?

Tags: stellaris

The way I make ships now is to click on each planet, go to the ships tab and add a corvette. If you've got 20 planets spread over 4 sectors however that takes a long time.

Is there an option to quickly build 20 ships spread over my 20 planets? I'm pretty sure I could do it in EU4.

The same with upgrading: it's annoying micromanagement to split your fleet into 20 parts, send them to the 20 planets, upgrade them and regrouping them. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Upgrade speed is supposedly being adjusted in an upcoming patch so that time is a function of the magnitude of the difference, rather than simply based on ship count and size. (Though splitting will always be more effective)

Answer (score 8):

Nope, as of now, there is no such feature.

Very likely to be added in the future, but at the moment, you have to do it manually.

Comment: I confirm, Dulkan is right. No ways at this moment to automatically produce ships.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not answering the question but it might ease the pain. 
The way I currently handle it is by creating a shortcut to the planets by:

1. Selecting planet [1..9]
2. [CTRL]+[1..9]

When I need to iterate through them I do the following:

1. Selecting the planet by clicking [1..9]
2. Creating a task (in this case - adding a ship to the construction queue of the spaceport).

HTH

Comment: That's useful to know. Similar to how I play SC2.

Answer (score 0):

I click on a planet, then press TAB to "go to next planet" then click on the spaceport to add ships to the queue. Zoom out a bit to make clicking on the spaceport easier. Press tab again for the next planet. This will even go to planets in sectors.

The hotkey method can also help, but has only 9 or 10 slots.